# Field Level Triggers - are they possible?

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger

Is it possible to execute a trigger on a field by itself instead of an object?

ObjectA.Field1  on update of Field1 run trigger.  On update of ObjectA.Field2 do nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would write the trigger on the object, and if you only want logic to be executed if a certain field has changed, you can compare the new and old values of that field and act accordingly:

```
trigger onFieldChange on Account (before update) {
    for (Account a : Trigger.new) {

        // retrieve the record prior to update DML in Trigger.oldMap
        Account oldAccount = Trigger.oldMap.get(a.Id);

        if (oldAccount.Name != a.Name) {
            // do something
        }
}
```

Comment: Also to keep in mind if you're comparing string values (answer by @sfdcfox): http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/65603/any-benefit-to-using-equals-instead-of-syntax/65605#65605